# How to get rid of multiple branch_id?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a SQL Query of this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(PERMISSION_ID) AS USER_TOTAL_PERMISSION_PER_BRANCH,
    USER_ID,
    BRANCH_ID
FROM BRANCH_PERMISSION_USER
GROUP BY USER_ID, BRANCH_ID
ORDER BY USER_ID, USER_TOTAL_PERMISSION_PER_BRANCH DESC
```

But I have a problem because I only want the first row per user_id. The main goal is to get the list of user together it's branch and top 1 or the distinct on the USER_TOTAL_PERMISSION_PER_BRANCH

Here is the sample output:

[image: click here]

Expected output should be:

```
[USER_TOTAL_PERMISSION_PER_BRANCH][USER_ID][BRANCH_ID]

135    1    1
135    2    1
134    3    1
1      4    1
1      5    1
1      6    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT USER_TOTAL_PERMISSION_PER_BRANCH, USER_ID, BRANCH_ID
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS USER_TOTAL_PERMISSION_PER_BRANCH,
             USER_ID, BRANCH_ID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM BRANCH_PERMISSION_USER
      GROUP BY USER_ID, BRANCH_ID
     ) ub
WHERE seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your query to a CTE a do filtering using correlation:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        count(permission_id) as user_total_permission_per_branch,
        user_id,
        branch_id
    from branch_permission_user
    group by user_id, branch_id
)
select c.* 
from cte c
where c.user_total_permission_per_branch = (
    select max(c1.user_total_permission_per_branch)
    from cte c1 
    where c1.user_id = c.user_id and c1.branch_id = c.branch_id
)
```

Comment: I got errors once I run this query. 

Here is the error message: 

`Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The multi-part identifier "cte1.user_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The multi-part identifier "cte1.branch_id" could not be bound.`

Comment: @Star: that was a typo, just fixed it.

Comment: Hi @GMB. I run the sql query but I got multiple user_id again with different branches. I want only one user_id, maybe the first row in order to get rid of multiple user_id

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sir @Gordon

I use his logic. Here is it:

```
SELECT USER_TOTAL_PERMISSION_PER_BRANCH, USER_ID, BRANCH_ID
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS USER_TOTAL_PERMISSION_PER_BRANCH,
             USER_ID, BRANCH_ID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM BRANCH_PERMISSION_USER
      GROUP BY USER_ID, BRANCH_ID
     ) ub
WHERE seqnum = 1
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Gordon already posted this as an answer. You should delete this answer and mark his as the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here at stackoverflow. Thanks for the info. ^_^ Am I right, I should click the check symbol on his comment? And click Up arrow? Thanks Sir @Sean